# "a horse most likely to win a race" x "a horse that doesn't seem to stand a chance"

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary, idiom-requests

Is there a single-word or noun phrase for a horse considered a favorite?  In fact, even more than a favorite: every bookmaker feels sure that horse is winning a forthcoming race.  e.g. "Twice Over" is certainly a ___________.

Also, at the other end of the spectrum, what is the word for that horse nobody gives any credit to, but ends up arriving first? In that case, if you place a bet on a __________ and it wins the race, you're likely to collect very good winnings.

Comment: In the parlance: *sure thing*, a *shoe in*, or, if the race is fixed, maybe a *ringer*? For the loser, some synonym of *lost cause*?

Comment: Overwhelming favorite, prohibitive favorite, or lock. Long shot.

Comment: *Rank outsider* for the second (UK).

Comment: I think the single word for a horse that's considered the favorite is "favorite".

Comment: @RichardKayser Knowledge of all this racetrack lingo leads me to believe that you are betting man! Richard, is there anything else you want to share with us? I think we should be told.

Comment: "Twice Over" is a certainty.

Comment: @PeterPoint Salutations. I have a drinking problem -- I'm not drinking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No such thing as a certainty in horse racing.

Comment: @RichardKayser Of all the gin joints in all the towns in all the world, you end up fessing on ELU! Certainty? Bah, humbug! So called dead certs in horse racing invariably end up as cans of dog food!

Comment: @Richard Kayser But 'certainty' is also idiomatic for 'firm favourite':
From [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certainty) **certainty** noun (EXTREMELY LIKELY) C2 [ C ] something that is very likely to happen:
_Joan will win - that's a certainty._
[ + to infinitive ] _Joan is a certainty to win._ // [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/certainty) gives the [lacking to-infinitive] version, but doesn't do well with the definition: A person that is certain to do or win the specified thing.
_he was expected to be a certainty for a gold medal_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, definitely, one might aver (believe), idiomatically, that "Twice Over is certain to win" or "Twice Over is a certainty". At the same time, one doesn't often see odds of 1 to infinity.

Comment: Is *dark horse* not used of actual horses in actual horse races? That seems like the obvious choice for the second half of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Favorite**:

> "Twice Over" is certainly a *lock*.

M-W:

> [*lock*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lock): one that is
>   assured of success or favorable outcome

Given that your tags did not specify *single-word request*, you could also consider *overwhelming favorite* and *prohibitive favorite*.

TFD:

> [*prohibitive*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prohibitive): so
>   likely to win as to discourage competition: *the prohibitive favorite
>   to win the nomination*

**Opposite of favorite**:

> Also, at the other end of the spectrum, what is the word for that
>   horse nobody gives any credit to, but ends up arriving first? In that
>   case, if you place a bet on a *long shot* and it wins the race, you're
>   likely to collect very good winnings.

M-W:

> [*long shot*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long+shot): an
>   entry (as in a horse race) given little chance of winning

I'm not aware of a single word for *long shot*.

Comment: Richard, well done! Right on the money, I'd say.

Comment: @PeterPoint I like that. Right on the money. :-)

Comment: I presume your answer refers to this specific jargon as used in the US.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Centaurus Correct. Common U.S. jargon, but *long shot* is also BrE according to M-W.

Answer (score 1):

1). *Twice Over* is certainly the **red-hot favorite** to win the Waco Derby.

**Red-hot favorite:** (*noun*) A horse, team, competitor, etc., that is very strongly fancied to win. (Oxford Dictionary)

2). If you place a bet on an *also-ran* and it wins the race, you're likely to collect very good winnings.

**also-ran:**  (*noun*) 1). Someone in a competition who is unlikely to do well or who has failed (Cambridge Dictionary) and 2). A horse or dog that finishes out of the money in a race (Merriam-Webster)